# Request in IAuthorizationPolicy

Tags: kinto

I'm trying to implement a custom `IAuthorizationPolicy` in Kinto. The documentation points to https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/authorization.html, which does not make me entirely understand how to add my `IAuthorizationPolicy` to the Kinto app.

My solution is to make it into a plugin, and implement the `includeme` function like this:

```
def includeme(config):
  custom_authorization_policy = CustomAuthorizationPolicy()
  config.set_authorization_policy(custom_authorization_policy)
```

But later, in `IAuthorizationPolicy#permits`, I would like to access the `request` that is currently being processed. This is because I want to [cache the authentication tokens](http://docs.kinto-storage.org/en/stable/tutorials/authentication-github.html?highlight=cache#cache-the-token-validation), and, as I understand it, the cache can be accessed from the `request`.

However, the `IAuthorizationPolicy#permits` takes the `context` parameter, and on it I can't find any request or cache.

Answer (score 0):

The cache, if supported, can be accessed on `config.registry.cache` aswell, so I'm injecting it into my Auth policy:

```
def includeme(config):
  custom_authorization_policy = CustomAuthorizationPolicy(config.registry.cache)
  config.set_authorization_policy(custom_authorization_policy)
```